# React native redux - Connect (Cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Pretty new to react-native developpement, apologies if my issue is obvious. I've been searching for quite a long time before posting.

It has been working perfectly for quite a long time.
I can't identify what I have done to break things up.

I believe I'm importing react redux properly, using {connect} properly. I didn't change the way I'm using it.

Also stacktrace is not really helping me ..

[Stacktrace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GesPd.png)

Github to my project if need be : 
[github](https://github.com/ImKrach/bkrcoran)

And the most important file :
[PageLecture.js](https://github.com/ImKrach/bkrcoran/blob/master/js/containers/PageLecture.js)

Also one thing weird I noticed, is that for some time this error was only occuring when I was using my phone, not emulator. Emulator was working fine. Now this error is also on emulator.

Answer (score -1):

OK so this was actually pretty dumb, and not related to redux connect method (as I thought initially).

It was due to me using at some point a Sound module which I was initializing wrongly (should have done that outside of my PageLecture class, then I can use it inside this very class).

I'd like to mark as solve but looks like I don't have this option available.